# .NET Unhandled Exception from MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, exception

I'm copying and pasting my application from one server (works fine) to another server (it doesn't work fine).

I get this on the new server, even though the code hasn't changed:

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   MasterPagePS_Index.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +117
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Comment: And after debugging this, what did you find, or what is at the line that the trace states?

Comment: You need to step through this and determine what the source of the null reference is

Comment: it works fine on my local and on my old server, trying to move this to the new one is the problem

Comment: Yes you already told us that it is a new server.  For the 3rd time now, need to step thru and determine the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: how do i debug remotely from my local to the new server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accessing a database, file, or any external resources? Sounds like you have a configuration difference, check your web.config.

Comment: i am using external stuff as in a database. but that seems to be okay. all my assemlies are in the bin folder too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `relative path` in oder to access your ressource (File, page, style, assembly , etc...)

so ASP.Net don't find your file, throw null exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error you provided doesn't give much information. I suggest that you perform a remote debugging and check which line is causing the error.

Or you can add the Global.asax file and catch the error in Application_Error and email the error to  yourself.

```
Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
Dim hue As System.Web.HttpUnhandledException = New System.Web.HttpUnhandledException(ex.Message, ex)
Dim html As String = hue.GetHtmlErrorMessage()
' TODO: Send the html string. This will send you the formatted html of the exception including the source of the error and stacktrace.
```